# How do I update a pre-formatted DataGridView bound to a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that I am binding to the Values collection of a dictionary.  In my form's constructor, I can create the dictionary and bind the columns of the DataGridView to fields in the structure that will be contained in the dictionary:

```
        m_tasks = new Dictionary<int,OperationsTaskLabeledData>();
        var taskArray = from task in m_tasks.Values select new {
        StartDate = task.m_start_task_date.ToString("M/dd H:mm"),
        EndDate = task.m_task_date.ToString("M/dd H:mm"),
        Description = task.m_short_desc,
        Object = task.m_device_id,
        InitialLocation = task.m_initial_location,
        FinalLocation = task.m_final_location };
        dgvFutureTasks.DataSource = taskArray.ToArray();
```

I want this code in the form's constructor so that the columns can be formatted, and I won't have to reformat them every time data in the grid is updated.

When I actually have data to display in this datagridview, what do I do with it?  I will call this function:

```
private void DisplayFutureTasks(IEnumerable<OperationsTaskLabeledData> tasks)
```

But I don't know what to do inside this function.

I can just re-bind the datagridview control and reformat all of the columns each time the control is updated, but that seems very wasteful.  I'm sure there's a better way to do it, and I'd much rather do this in some reasonable fashion instead of using ugly brute force.

Comment: Sorry about the omission.  WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

I have now figured out how to do what I want to do.

I know the columns I will need at design time, so in the IDE I add the columns to my datagridview and format them as desired.  I then set the AutoGenerateColumns property of the grid view to false.  For some unknown reason, that property is not available in the designer and has to be set in code.  Finally, I can set the DataPropertyName of each column to the name of the corresponding field in the structure I will be linking to.  For example, here is the LINQ code I will be using to generate the data source:

```
taskArray = from task in tasks select new {
                                StartDate = task.m_start_task_date.ToString("M/dd H:mm"),
                                EndDate = task.m_task_date.ToString("M/dd H:mm"),
                                Description = task.m_short_desc,
                                Object = task.m_device_id,
                                InitialLocation = task.m_initial_location,
                            FinalLocation = task.m_final_location };
.DataSource = taskArray.ToArray();
```

And here is the code in my form's constructor to set the DataPropertyName properties:

```
dgvFutureTasks.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgvFutureTasks.Columns["colStartTime"].DataPropertyName = "StartDate";
dgvFutureTasks.Columns["colFinishTime"].DataPropertyName = "EndDate";
dgvFutureTasks.Columns["colDescription"].DataPropertyName = "Description";
dgvFutureTasks.Columns["colObject"].DataPropertyName = "Object";
dgvFutureTasks.Columns["colInitialLocation"].DataPropertyName = "InitialLocation";
dgvFutureTasks.Columns["colFinalLocation"].DataPropertyName = "FinalLocation";
```

At this point, the DataGridView displayed the data as expected.

RobR